# Laravel Offline PWA: Data Sync and View Fallback using TALL Stack

Tags: progressive-web-apps, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Can Laravel with Livewire be used to create a PWA that completely works offline (static HTML views), stores data client-side and syncs when re-connected to the internet?

Comment: I don't think so. Livewire focus is on return HTML from the back-end so I believe there's no way you can achieve PWA offline state without having too much work. It would be better to use javascript only to use a PWA.